# NGINX ERROR :connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, web-deployment

I get that error in title when I cat out the error.log

this is how I set my website config inside `/etc/nginx/site-availables/ArticleWebsite`:

```
server_tokens               off;
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/ArticleWebsite.access.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/ArticleWebsite.error.log;

# This configuration will be changed to redirect to HTTPS later
server {
  server_name               backend.globeofarticles.com;
  listen                    443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.globeofarticles.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.globeofarticles.com/privkey.pem;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  }
}
```

to explain my situation better, `backend.globeofarticles.com` is the subdomain, that where the requests are sent from `globeofarticles.com` or `www.globeofarticles.com`.

Also, Django has `127.0.0.1:8000` host as default.

when I access the website (backend subdomain) I get this error:

[image]

when checking network tab, I get too many redirects actually:

[image]

with status code 301

Answer (score 0):

try this for ur nginx config. then u can reinstall certbot for this domain. using    certbot --nginx

```
   server {
   server_name backend.globeofarticles.com;
   root /var/www/backend.globeofarticles.com/html/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 
   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }
 
   location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;

   }

  # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
   location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           360d;
   }

   # disable access to hidden files
   location ~ /\.ht {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
       deny all;
   }
```

Comment: the nginx config is supposed to be in the same path i mentioned above in the question, or is that the one in `default`?

Comment: @Ghazi if you want in sites available you have to link to enabled. use this command   ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-availables/ArticleWebsite.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ArticleWebsite.conf  and make sure Nginx.conf has this line include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf; then restart nginx

Comment: unfortunately, your solution did not fix it at all.

Comment: remove cloudflare dns proxy @Ghazi

Comment: remove cloudflare dns proxy WAS IT! @Gokuhan21 Appreciate it!